# why would url not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the code

```
<span id="urlWindow"  style="float:right;" value="http://www.mysite.com">Open Url</span>
```

the sizeUrl has the value of http://www.mysite.com

but the following code doesnt load

```
var sizeUrl = $('#urlWindow').attr('value');

    newWindow.document.write(
        '<html>' +
            '<iframe src=" + sizeUrl + " width="100%" height="100%">'+

        '</iframe>' +

         '</html>'
```

where as this one does

```
 var sizeUrl = $('#urlWindow').attr('value');

            newWindow.document.write(
                '<html>' +
                    '<iframe src=" http://www.mysite.com "  width="100%" height="100%">'+

                '</iframe>' +

                 '</html>'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'<iframe src="' + sizeUrl + '" width="100%" height="100%">'
```

You weren't breaking the string to include your variable.